# Element is acting as if it has fixed positioning

Tags: html, css, sass, scroll

so I've been looking around for the solution to this problem and I haven't been able to find a clear or really any answers at all (maybe I just don't know how to word the question?). So, I'm really going to rely on pictures for this question and then explain what is going on.

[Starting position of chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZYOs.png)

Above is the starting position of the element (the content just above the dev tools). At this position, the elements are functioning as they should, however on resizing the dev tools, the elements move up or down. In the next picture, I increased the size of the dev tools and the elements in question move with the tools.

[Expanded size of chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG4ph.png)

As you can see in the picture above, when I resize the dev tools, the page elements and next button moves almost like it's attached to the dev tools.

What really confuses me is that I haven't used css on any part of the in questioned elements. And what confuses me even more is the fact that no other element on the page reacts the same way as the element in question (which again is the very last elements on the page).

Below is my html and SCSS code:

HTML:

```
<section class="section__shopping-items quarter-margin">
      <div class="item-content flex-wrapper">
        <div class="shop-list">
          <img
            src="../../public/css/img/3-stripes-shorts-black.jpg"
            alt="pants"
            class="item-img"
          />
          <div class="item-info">
            <p class="gender-collection">
              Women's Originals
            </p>
            <p class="item--name">3-stripes shorts</p>
            <p class="item--price">
              &#36;45
            </p>
            <p class="item--colors">
              2 colors
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="shop-list">
          <img
            src="../../public/css/img/3-stripes-shorts-black.jpg"
            alt="pants"
            class="item-img"
          />
          <div class="item-info">
            <p class="gender-collection">
              Women's Originals
            </p>
            <p class="item--name">3-stripes shorts</p>
            <p class="item--price">
              &#36;45
            </p>
            <p class="item--colors">
              2 colors
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="shop-list">
          <img
            src="../../public/css/img/3-stripes-shorts-black.jpg"
            alt="pants"
            class="item-img"
          />
          <div class="item-info">
            <p class="gender-collection">
              Women's Originals
            </p>
            <p class="item--name">3-stripes shorts</p>
            <p class="item--price">
              &#36;45
            </p>
            <p class="item--colors">
              2 colors
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="shop-list">
          <img
            src="../../public/css/img/3-stripes-shorts-black.jpg"
            alt="pants"
            class="item-img"
          />
          <div class="item-info">
            <p class="gender-collection">
              Women's Originals
            </p>
            <p class="item--name">3-stripes shorts</p>
            <p class="item--price">
              &#36;45
            </p>
            <p class="item--colors">
              2 colors
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section__next-page quarter-margin">
        <div class="flex-wrapper space-flex">
            <div class="page--select">
                <div class="flex-wrapper">
                    <p>Page:</p>
                    <div class="select-page flex-wrapper">
                        <p class="page--num">1 <span>&#8964;</span></p>
                        <p class="page--length">of 9</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page--next">
                <button class="next">next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

SCSS

```
// shopping items
.section {
    &__shopping-items {
        height: 100%;

        .item-content {
            cursor: pointer;
            justify-content: space-between;
            overflow: auto;
            .shop-list {
                border: .1rem solid transparent;
                min-width: 25%;
                // height: 25%;
            
                img {
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .item-info {
                    // margin: 1rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
                    margin: 0 1rem;

                    .gender-collection {
                        margin: 1rem 0;
                        font-size: 1.2rem;
                        font-weight: 100;
                        color: $collection-name-font;
                    }

                    .item {
                        &--name,
                        &--price {
                            font-weight: 300;
                        }

                        &--name {
                            margin-bottom: .7rem;
                            font-size: 1.3rem;
                        }

                        &--price {
                            margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
                            font-size: 1.2rem;
                        }

                        &--colors {
                            margin-bottom: 1rem;
                            font-size: 1.1rem;
                            font-weight: 300;
                            color: $collection-name-font;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .shop-list:hover {
            border: .1rem solid $font-color;
        }
    }
}
```

Also a quick side note, I've not set anything on this page to `position:fixed`.

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you have an item that's height is set to 100%, the height of the item will change when the height of it's parent changes. In this case, when you adjust the height of the devtools you are adjusting the height and width of the viewport. If you want the height to be fixed, use something like height : 500px; instead

Comment: @zjb That worked. Thank's for the solution!